# Excel index match plus search

Tags: excel, indexing, excel-formula, data-analysis

I have 4 columns

- column A is the range for lookup
- Column B is set of strings per cell in A
- column C is the lookup value of the columnA
- column D is a sentence that may/may not contain the string in column B.

I need to find first if C is in Column A and if found, i need to check if the value in column B in reference of the cell in A is present anywhere in cell D.

This may be confusing but let me put it in a image.

I tried using index match and search but always not referencing to what i want.
Hope you can help! Thanks

[image]

Comment: `=COUNTIF(D2,"*"&INDEX($B$2:$B$5,MATCH(C2,$A$2:$A$5,0))&"*")>0`

Comment: Welcome! Can you please read about [the problems with images images of text](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541) and then [edit] to convert your images of tables into markup tables? See [/editing-help#tables](/editing-help#tables) for how. You might find [tablesgenerator.com](//www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables) useful.

Answer (score 0):

Besides the solution commented above, you may try this as well using `XLOOKUP()` & `SEARCH()` wrapped within an `ISNUMBER()`

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `E2`

```
=ISNUMBER(SEARCH(XLOOKUP(C2:C5,A2:A5,B2:B5),D2:D5))
```

---

Or, without `#SPILL`

• Formula used in cell `F2`

```
=ISNUMBER(SEARCH(INDEX($B$2:$B$5,MATCH(C2,$A$2:$A$5,0)),D2))
```

Fill Down for the rest of the cells !!

---